# Searching for and then validating in Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to be able to search a User ID in a .csv file in Python and then validate whether the password matches the User ID.  Any suggestions where I have gone wrong would be appreciated please

Code so far!

Comment: why dont you use any database instead?

Comment: don't down what scenarios you are in

Answer (score 0):

if id's are under heading id

```
passwd = input("please enter you id ")

with open("data.csv", 'r') as f:
        r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in r:
            # skips the headers without next
            if row['id'] == passwd:
                print("the Id is valid")
```